# UI Automation - Get-UiaPane : failed to get control in 5000 milliseconds

Tags: powershell, ui-automation

[image][image]

I am trying to achieve a click on the button "Install Now". However I keep encountering this error. Currently using UIAutomation.0.8.7B3.NET40 version of UIA and PSVersion 5.1.19041.610

edit: it clearly says control type is pane and I am using Get-UiaPane

Comment: Please insert PowerShell code as text, because screenshots can be hard to read and cannot be searched for. It is OK to use screenshots for apps only. Anyway I would advise against UI Automation PowerShell module. It has various issues and is no longer maintained. You will propably have more success using [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver).

Comment: Thanks zett42, I'll looks into other alternatives